# How to disable address bar expansion in Mozilla Firefox 77?

Tags: firefox, address-bar, firefox-77

With the latest update to Firefox, there is a feature that I would like to disable. When you open a window/tab or place the cursor in into the address bar, it becomes a bit bigger. How can I disable / reset this behavior?

*address bar before update*

[image: Firefox before update]

*address bar after update*

[image: Firefox after update]

<sub>Some time ago I asked the same question to [Firefox 75](https://superuser.com/questions/1539855/how-to-disable-address-bar-expansion-in-mozilla-firefox-75) and got an [answer](https://superuser.com/a/1539929/194560) with a working solution. But the solution for `v75` doesn't work for the `v77`.</sub>

Comment: You can submit feedback to Mozilla about this feature: https://input.mozilla.org/feedback/firefox/77.0?utm_source=releasenotes

Answer (score 6):

The edits to about:config that worked for earlier versions of Firefox don't work for version 77, but the same results can be achieved through implementation of a userChrome.css file.

A good tutorial on how to create the file can be found at https://www.userchrome.org/how-create-userchrome-css.html, and the content that you need to place in the file has already been worked up and published at https://raw.githubusercontent.com/WesleyBranton/userChrome.css-Customizations/master/css/remove_megabar.css.

I have performed this modification on Firefox 77 running under user-level rights on Windows 10 Enterprise, and it restored the normal url bar.

Comment: The raw.github link 404

Comment: I think the author of that content had it on github as a temporary location.  Sorry for the inconvenience, but I've found it again at https://www.reddit.com/r/FirefoxCSS/comments/fxez4e/remove_new_megabar_grow_shrink_effect/  If that link goes away, I'll post the code, but I felt that the original author should get the credit for it.

Comment: Thanks, style works however how to open old history on focus? Not is not possible by mouse - only press key down.

Comment: I apologize for being unable to help with that one.  That feature might be configurable in the userChrome css file, but it's one that I don't use, so I haven't attempted to implement it.